# Is cql an abstraction implemented on top of thrift?

Tags: cassandra

I'm having difficulty establishing how cql is implemented at the lowest level. Is it still making calls to the thrift interface or is it something completely different

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use CQL from either Thrift or the new native binary protocol.  However the native drivers provide much better support for the more sophisticated Cassandra functions.  Thrift is essentially deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, I'd like to add that CQL (and its drivers) interact with Cassandra via a new, binary protocol, and not via Thrift.  The original row/column structure of Cassandra is still intact, but it is largely abstracted away by CQL.

There was a great blog post done on this subject out on Planet Cassandra: [Understanding How CQL3 Maps To Cassandra’s Internal Data Structure](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/).  It makes for quick read, and has some simple examples that explain how the abstraction provided by CQL3 functions.  I highly recommend running through the examples yourself on your own, local Cassandra instance.